# GWT - Modify existing object or create a new one

Tags: hibernate, gwt, serialization, reflection, immutability

I am working on a GWT + Hibernate project. It involves a Company entity (and hence, a table, too).

The UI has a view that lists all the companies. The user can edit an existing company through that view.

My question is - How do I incorporate the modified data? Should I modify the existing, retrieved Company entity object, or should I create a new instance that contains the new data?

The former would save creation of a new instance, and a possible copying of unmodified data. However, it means exposing setters for each field of the Company. This goes against reducing mutability.

The latter option would create one new instance, and might involve copying unmodified data. However, it will save me from exposing setters, thus encouraging immutability.

Which one is recommended?

Also, does Deferred Binding / Reflection or Serialization require all getter/setters to be present? In that case, my question becomes moot, as I will have to provide them anyways.

EDIT - I am using GWT-RPC for communication with server.

Comment: What are you using to communicate with your server? GWT-RPC? RequestFactory? hand-made JSON+RequestBuilder?

Comment: @ThomasBroyer - GWT-RPC. I have added that to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GWT-RPC doesn't mandate getters and setters. It'll use them it they exist but will directly inject the fields otherwise. It's however incapable of dealing with [`final` fields](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=1054) (you can mitigate this by leaving your fields non-final and only exposing getters, or doing [your own GWT-RPC serialization for the class](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/rpc/CustomFieldSerializer.html)).

Now, as you're saying these objects are your JPA/Hibernate entities, I believe JPA wants mutable objects, so that would answer the question.

Another thing to look at is how you'll bind your entity to your UI. The [Editor framework](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiEditors) for instance mandates mutable objects too.

You might also want to send back to the server different objects than an entity (e.g. command objects similar to *operation transforms*) in such a way that you wouldn't have to mutate or create a new object on the client-side (you'd still have to resolve the issue on the server-side, but it's out of GWT's scope then).

In the light of the above, I'd say you should go with mutability of your objects, because the APIs you're using (JPA/Hibernate, GWT-RPC) or might want to consider (Editors) all mandate or work best with mutable objects.

Note that RequestFactory uses, on the client-side, *frozen objects*: they're only mutable in a given context, for a given time frame. On the server-side, mutability is a must though (but you can consider freezing your objects as well, or using a builder pattern)

Comment: OK. But that means I can at least get rid of non-essential setters, so that some fields can't be changed directly. Is that good?

Comment: I doubt such a question is good fit for StackOverflow: people will argue for it, or against it, but I don't think there's a definitive answer. If you're asking for my opinion, I'd say: go with mutable objects.

Comment: Hmm. After re-reading your answer, it seems that the pain of managing immutable entities would override its advantages in my case (GWT + GWT-RPC + JPA). I also can't replace any of the technology/framework of my project. So, mutable objects seem to be the way to go. I will wait for a day, however, for other answers.